# Compare double value in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-6

Why is that even if enter value 999999, it will always go to else statement? Can someone explain why and what is the correct way to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    double dValue = 0;

    scanf("%d",&dValue);

    if(10000 < dValue){
            printf("More than");
    } else {
        printf("Less than");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `%f` or `%g` in the `scanf` call.

Comment: `%d` -> `%lf`, Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: `%d` does *not* mean `double`.  It means decimal conversion to `int`.

Comment: @wallyk thanks. changed to %lf, and it works fine. but I print the value of dValue, its still printing the 999999 value. why is it still wrong when I try to compare it in the if statement, which is comparing 999999 with another int value?

Comment: @Azuan:  You enter 99999 or 999999 and the program prints "less than"?  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @wallyk lets say I use the same code as above. then I enter 999999. why does it still skipping the if statement? shouldn't 10000 < 999999 should be true?

Comment: @Azuan:  Yes it should.  So it should print `More than`.  What does it actually do?

Comment: @wallyk weird. it seems it will always print Less than.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13593/discussion-between-wallyk-and-azuan)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're intending to read in the value as an integer (using `"%d"`), then you should declare it to be an `int`. If you're intending to read in the value as a `double`, then you should instead use `"%lf"` as your scanf format specifier.

Comment: changed to %lf, and it works fine. but I print the value of dValue, its still printing the 999999 value. why is it still wrong when I try to compare it in the if statement, which is comparing 999999 with another int value?

Comment: @Azuan How are you trying to print `dValue`?

Comment: I use %d to print the value, since I use  %d to scanf. lets say I use the same code as above. then I enter 999999. why does it still skipping the if statement? shouldn't 10000 < 999999 should be true?

Comment: @Azuan To be clear, you're saying that you've fixed the bug, declared `dValue` as an `int`, use `"%d"` with `scanf`, input a number larger than 10000, and you're seeing the `else` branch of the `if` condition executed?

Comment: not actually. I use the same code as above, which mean I didn't fix the bug yet. then I input number lager than 10000, but it still go to the 'else' statement

Comment: @Azuan Fix the bug. The bug is causing the value to get garbled.

Comment: I think you are entering a number which is greater than maximum value of int. So compiler calculates its equivalent and it turns out to be less than 10000.
Suppose you are entering 20000 and you maximum allowed integer value is 19000(assume). Then 20000 will be treated as -1000. And -1000 is less than 10000. The size of integer depends on the compiler. Please check the maximum value of integer for your compiler.